# How to convert an atomic vector to a recursive vector where I can use "$" symbol in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
money_supply <-matrix(c(1,2.25,2.81,2,2.27,2.84,3,2.28,2.86,4,2.29,2.88,5,2.31,2.90,6,2.32,2.92,7,2.35,2.96,8,2.37,2.99,9,2.40,3.02,10,2.42,3.04,11,2.43,3.05,12,2.42,3.05,13,2.44,3.08,14,2.47,3.10,15,2.49,3.10,16,2.51,3.13,17,2.53,3.17,18,2.53,3.18,19,2.54,3.19,20,2.55,3.20),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(money_supply)<-c("Month","M2","M3")
rownames(money_supply)<-c(" ")
money_supply <- as.table(money_supply)
money_supply

money_supply<-as.data.frame(t(money_supply))
```

That is my code, I am trying to create a 3x3 table from those data. It pops out as a table but then I cannot compute the data. I want to find the mean for the column M2 by using mean$M2, but it doesn't work, an error saying $ operator is invalid for atomic vector, so I convert "money_supply" to a recursive vector, but then I still can't compute data from column M1, and M2. Can anyone helps me with this?

Comment: I mean, how can I change my 3 variables to Month, M3 and M2?

Comment: Can you include how your result 3x3 matrix look like?, and also your line `rownames(money_supply)<-c(" ")` results in error, please correct to proper dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're looking for is called a **data.frame** in R.

Convert your matrix of data to a data.frame, and then call `mean(money_supply$M2)`:

```
money_supply <-matrix(c(1,2.25,2.81,2,2.27,2.84,3,2.28,2.86,4,2.29,2.88,5,2.31,2.90,6,2.32,2.92,7,2.35,2.96,8,2.37,2.99,9,2.40,3.02,10,2.42,3.04,11,2.43,3.05,12,2.42,3.05,13,2.44,3.08,14,2.47,3.10,15,2.49,3.10,16,2.51,3.13,17,2.53,3.17,18,2.53,3.18,19,2.54,3.19,20,2.55,3.20),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)

money_supply <- as.data.frame(money_supply)

colnames(money_supply) <- c("Month", "M2", "M3")

mean(money_supply$M2)
```

Or, skip the matrix part entirely:

```
money_supply <- data.frame(
    Month = 1:20, 
    M2    = seq(2.25, by=0.02, length.out=20),
    M3    = seq(2.81, by=0.03, length.out=20)
)

mean(money_supply$M2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this: `M2` is second column of your `table money_supply`

```
mean(money_supply[,2])
```

Output:

```
[1] 2.4085
```

So your total code is:

```
money_supply <-matrix(c(1,2.25,2.81,2,2.27,2.84,3,2.28,2.86,4,2.29,2.88,5,2.31,2.90,6,2.32,2.92,7,2.35,2.96,8,2.37,2.99,9,2.40,3.02,10,2.42,3.04,11,2.43,3.05,12,2.42,3.05,13,2.44,3.08,14,2.47,3.10,15,2.49,3.10,16,2.51,3.13,17,2.53,3.17,18,2.53,3.18,19,2.54,3.19,20,2.55,3.20),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(money_supply)<-c("Month","M2","M3")
money_supply <- as.table(money_supply)
mean(money_supply[,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is this what you want, but you can try the so called `apply` functions to obtain summaries on your data.frame (more in `?apply`)

```
money_supply <-matrix(c(1,2.25,2.81,2,2.27,2.84,3,2.28,2.86,4,2.29,2.88,5,2.31,2.90,6,2.32,2.92,7,2.35,2.96,8,2.37,2.99,9,2.40,3.02,10,2.42,3.04,11,2.43,3.05,12,2.42,3.05,13,2.44,3.08,14,2.47,3.10,15,2.49,3.10,16,2.51,3.13,17,2.53,3.17,18,2.53,3.18,19,2.54,3.19,20,2.55,3.20),ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(money_supply)<-c("Month","M2","M3")
apply(money_supply[,c(2,3)],MARGIN = 2,FUN = mean) #MARGIN =2 means you are taking your function by columns
    M2     M3 
2.4085 3.0235
```